# SQL to move value to new column based on value

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

We have a table like the example below:

```
TS                          |Description        |Value
--------------------------------------------------------
2020-06-12 14:13:12.253     |Machine Status     |Event 4
2020-06-12 14:12:56.250     |Machine Status     |Event 3
2020-06-12 14:12:26.250     |Machine Status     |Event 2
2020-06-12 14:11:06.253     |Machine Status     |Event 1
2020-06-12 14:10:12.253     |Machine Status     |Event 4
2020-06-12 14:09:56.250     |Machine Status     |Event 3
2020-06-12 14:09:26.250     |Machine Status     |Event 2
2020-06-12 14:08:06.253     |Machine Status     |Event 1
```

We want to transpose the timestamps based on the event

```
TS_Event4                   |TS_Event3                   |TimeDiff
------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-06-12 14:13:12.253     |2020-06-12 14:12:56.250     |Event4-Event3
2020-06-12 14:10:12.253     |2020-06-12 14:09:56.250     |Event4-Event3
....
```

Now the tricky part... 
I sort the table on timestamps and need to find the first 'event4'. The next 'event3'(not always the next row) needs to be in the column next to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when value = 'Event 4' then ts end),
       max(case when value = 'Event 3' then ts end),
       datediff(second,
                max(case when value = 'Event 1' then ts end),
                max(case when value = 'Event 2' then ts end)
               )
from t;
```

EDIT:

For your modified question, you can add a `group by` key by counting the sequential number for each event:

```
select max(case when value = 'Event 4' then ts end),
       max(case when value = 'Event 3' then ts end),
       datediff(second,
                max(case when value = 'Event 1' then ts end),
                max(case when value = 'Event 2' then ts end)
               )
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by value order by ts) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```

Comment: Thats the format I need!
But by using the max function I only get 1 row returned.
Would it be possible to get a bunch of rows from previously occured events?

Comment: @AndyJansen . . . In general, I am *very* reluctant to answer modified questions that invalidate anyone's answer -- I don't like playing the game of "guess the question".  I did answer this time, but in general, it is better to just ask a new question.